# Queries return incorrect values with multi-level single table inheritance using Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

In my project I have the following class hierarchy, using Mongoid with STI:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
end

class SpecificUser < User
end

class MoreSpecificUser < SpecificUser
end
```

Mongoid gives me the correct result when I query `User.count` and `MoreSpecificUser.count`, but returns 0
when I try `SpecificUser.count`. Only after I query `MoreSpecificUser.count` it returns the correct value
for `SpecificUser.count`. Is there a way to make the queries in SpecificUser return the correct values
without querying its subclasses before?

Note: It was working with MongoMapper before, it only broke after I migrated to Mongoid.

My mongoid.yml:

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: dev_project
      hosts:
        - 127.0.0.1:27017
      options:
        preload_models: true
        max_pool_size: 16
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
```

I'm using Mongoid 5, MongoDB 2.6, Ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 4.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like adding `config.mongoid.preload_models = true` in application.rb solves it.

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#model-preloading